The formal power series analogue of the divided power polynomial algebra
For the purposes of this discussion, rings are associative, commutative, and unital.
Let $k$ be a ring.
An ordinary differential $k$-algebra is a $k$-algebra $A$ equipped with an additive $k$-linear endomorphism $\delta : A \to A$ satisfying the Leibniz product rule:
$$\delta (x y) = x \delta (y) + \delta (x) y$$
The category of ordinary differential $k$-algebras is a finitary algebraic category, i.e. the forgetful functor to $\textbf{Set}$ is monadic and preserves filtered colimits.
In particular, it has a left adjoint.
Furthermore, the forgetful functor to $\textbf{Alg}_k$ has both left and right adjoints.
This is essentially because the free ordinary differential $k$-algebra on one generator has a coring structure.
Indeed, let $B$ be a ring.
We can equip $B^\mathbb{N}$ with the structure of an ordinary differential $B$-algebra $W (B)$ as follows:

The scalars map $B \to W (B)$ is $b \mapsto (b, 0, 0, \ldots)$.

Addition is degreewise.

Multiplication is the same as for exponential generating functions, i.e. given $(b_0, b_1, b_2, \ldots)$ and $(c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots)$, the $n$-th coefficient of their product is:
$$\sum_{r = 0}^n \frac{n!}{r! (n - r)!} b_r c_{n - r}$$

$\delta$ is the left shift operator.
Note that the Leibniz product rule can be seen here as a generalisation of the recurrence relation underlying Pascal's triangle.


It is straightforward to verify that $W$ so defined is a right adjoint for the forgetful functor to the category of $k$-algebras.
It should go without saying that $f = (1, 1, 1, \ldots)$, which is invariant under left shift, provides a solution in $W (B)$ to the ordinary differential equation $\delta (f) = f$.
Observe also that we have a $B$-algebra homomorphism $B [[z]] \to W (B)$ sending $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n z^n$ to the sequence $(b_0, \ldots, n! b_n, \ldots)$; of course, this maps the formal power series derivative to the left shift operator.
Thus, the elements of $W (B)$ should be considered formal power series analogues of divided power polynomials (in one variable over $B$).
Question.
Is the algebra $W (B)$ well known and studied?
What is it usually called?
(The notation I am using is meant to suggest an analogy with Witt vectors and Joyal $\delta$-rings, which are very similar but more complicated because of, well, arithmetic.)

This variant of $A[[x]]$ is studied for example in

William F. Keigher, On the ring of hurwitz series, https://doi.org/10.1080/00927879708825957


William F. Keigher, F.Leon Pritchard, Hurwitz series as formal functions, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(98)00099-1

and is called the ring $H(A)$ of Hurwitz series over $A$. The adjunction is also mentioned. In the slides Divided power algebras with derivations it is called the ring of formal divided power series over $A$, and this term is also used in other places.

I wonder why Keigher calls these Hurwitz series...

I don't know either. I don't have access to the first paper. But there he cites this one: Hurwitz , A. 1899 . Sur un théorème de M. Hadamard , Vol. 128 , 350 – 353 . C.R. Acad. Sc. So maybe the answer is there.

Ah, then it must have to do with the multiplication law. The naïve degreewise product is sometimes called the Hadamard product, and apparently the one here with binomial coefficients is sometimes called the Hurwitz (shuffle) product…
